# Is there a faster way to bind X and Y values to a C# Winforms Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am looking to plot up to 500 or so Line Series on a Winforms Chart.  I am currently storing the X and Y data values for each line series as arrays of double:

```
        double[][] secondArray = new double[1000][];  // holds the y-values for all signals plotted
        double[] firstArray;                          // holds the x-values for all signals plotted
```

The number of Y-values is determined by the size of the binary file that stores the data.  This value is captured as maxArrayIdx and is typically about 14,000.  The number of Line Series to plot is stored as analogDataFilesToPlot.Count.

```
            firstArray = new double[maxArrayIdx];  // Holds the x-values for all signals plotted, shared by all signals.
            for (int i = 0; i < analogDataFilesToPlot.Count; i++)
            {
                // Each array holds the y-values for a particular signal
                secondArray[i] = new double[maxArrayIdx];
            }
```

After capturing all the data to be plotted in these arrays, I am binding it to my chart with the following code.  Using the stopwatch, it is taking a little more than 5 seconds to do the loop below with about 250 files.  The application is currently running just a single thread.

```
            stopwatch1.Start();

            // Bind the array data to a Line Series
            for (int i = 0; i < analogDataFilesToPlot.Count; i++)
            {
                chart1.Series[i].Points.DataBindXY(firstArray, secondArray[i]);
            }

            stopwatch1.Stop();
```

I realize that this a lot of data, but is there a better/faster way to store and bind my X and Y values?

I was initially binding the data one point at a time using AddXY(), but that was significantly slower.

Comment: Please have a [look](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) at that *performance-rant*, specifically the 5th part. I think you will find the article informational. On another note, there's many things happening behind the `DataBindXY` method, if you want to see what it's doing, please see the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/Common/DataManager/DataPoint.cs,f21d334a0ca29a48) for more.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ - Thanks for the links.  I have bookmarked the "source code" link for future use as well.  On my machine, the `DataBindXY` works twice as fast as the `AddXY`.  I am new to c# and Charts so I am just wondering if there is another way of doing this that will be faster still.

Comment: Is it a ChartType.FastLine? Also: Maybe you can prepare the Series including the points and only add them when they are loaded?

Comment: @TaW - It was not a FastLine, just Line.  Thanks for the tip.  I changed all Series to FastLine and while it did not speed up the `DataBind` loop, it most certainly sped up the time it takes to draw all the data (for 250 lines from about 9 seconds to about 2 seconds). I am only binding the data when I want to display them.  I think that is what you mean by _when they are loaded_.

Comment: "I was initially binding the data one point at a time using AddXY(), but that was significantly slower."  - Try calling `SuspendUpdates` on the DataPointCollection (i.e. `Series.Points`) before the loop to add the points; then call `ResumeUpdates` after the loop.  If I recall correctly, the DataBind method just enumerates the source and adds the points, so you could eliminate the overhead of array creation by adding the points directly with `AddZY`.

Comment: @tto80: No, I meant: Create a Series in code without adding it to the chart's Series collection. Then add all the points and only then add the series to the chart. This way it needs to do the layout only once per series..

Comment: @TnTinMn - Thanks for the suggestion.  Using your `SuspendUpdates` method with the `AddXY` makes this in-line with my `DataBindXY` method and perhaps 5-10% faster in my initial experiments.  I appreciate the help from all who have commented!